# HtmlAgilityPack can't find element

Tags: c#, parsing, html-agility-pack

I need to parse a site and I know where to find the element I'm searching: it's a `span` with `class="metadata_with_icon-tags-primary_tag"`.

My C# code:

```
var page = new HtmlWeb().Load(url).DocumentNode.Descendants("span").Where(d => d.Attributes.Contains("class") && d.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("metadata_with_icon-tags-primary_tag"));
```

Item that I need:
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
HtmlWeb website = new HtmlWeb();
            var html = website.Load("https://genius.com/Eminem-space-bound-lyrics").DocumentNode.InnerHtml;  

            Regex rgx = new Regex(@"<script\b[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/script>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            var matches = rgx.Matches(html);
            var g = matches[14].Value;

            Regex regex = new Regex(
                @"(\[{.*}\])",
                RegexOptions.Multiline
            );

            Match match = regex.Match(g);
            var json = match.Value;
```

Comment: `content` is null

Comment: @SmiLe I checked your link in my test code and found that HtmlAgilityPack returned different html page then browser and he does not contain "metadata_with_icon-tags-primary_tag". As far as I understood you need data 'Genre". Pack returned us html where all data stored in JS. You can check it by debug. You can't parse javascript with HTML Agility Pack, it only supports HTML parsing. You should you'll  parse the javascript with another method (regex, js grammar, etc.)

Comment: @Smile I updated my answer. I hope it will help to you.

Answer (score 0):

To get your `span` with `class="metadata_with_icon-tags-primary_tag"`:

```
HtmlNode node = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='metadata_with_icon-tags-primary_tag']");
```

Comment: `node ` is null

Comment: Is your file properly loaded? Do you have something in your root node?

Comment: Yes, if I try to get some class upper I got it. Example I can get `song_metadata`

Comment: I suggest you try to use the [Genius API](https://docs.genius.com/) instead of trying to parse the HTML of the WebSite. Some parts are not loaded  (the span you're searching) with the HtmlAgilityPack. An example of data returned (JSON format): [https://genius.com/api/songs/561/](https://genius.com/api/songs/561/)